# Creating Pytorch variables directly on GPU seems to still create variable on CPU first, judging by CPU RAM usage

Tags: pytorch

I need to create variables directly on the GPU because I am very limited in my CPU ram.

I found the method to do this here

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-create-a-tensor-on-gpu-as-default/2128/3

Which mentions using

`torch.set_default_tensor_type(‘torch.cuda.FloatTensor’)`

However, when I tried

```
torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')
pytorchGPUDirectCreate = torch.FloatTensor(20000000, 128).uniform_(-1, 1).cuda()
```

It still seemed to take up mostly CPU RAM, before being transferred to GPU ram.

I am using Google Colab. To view RAM usage during the variable creation process, after running the cell, go to Runtime -> Manage Sessions

With and without using `torch.set_default_tensor_type('torch.cuda.FloatTensor')` , the CPU RAM bumps up to 11.34 GB while GPU ram stays low, and then GPU RAM goes to 9.85 and CPU ram goes back down.

It seems that `torch.set_default_tensor_type(‘torch.cuda.FloatTensor’)` didn't make a difference

For convenience here's a direct link to a notebook anyone can directly run

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LxPMHl8yFAATH0i0PBYRURo5tqj0_An7